# RabbitMQ Eventing Basic Consumer

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Looking at the example code from Rabbit MQ's site for a consumer...

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
    using(var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using(var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
                             durable: false,
                             exclusive: false,
                             autoDelete: false,
                             arguments: null);

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            var body = ea.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
        };
        channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello",
                             autoAck: true,
                             consumer: consumer);

        Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

It initially looked like the messages were coming off the queue 1 by 1 in order and handled consecutively by the code inside the Received section.

However the result I am now seeing suggests that they are probably coming off 1 by 1 in order, but being handle concurrently, is this correct?

Regards

Tom

Comment: you can control it by calling `channel.BasicQos(0, <MaxConcurrentConsumerThreads>, false);`

Comment: @FrankNielsen Thanks for your quick reply, so channel.BasicQos(0,1,false) will result in the messages coming off the queue 1 at time and handled by the event handler to the end before the next being handled? I need to ensure the messages are handled in the correct order and completely before the next is attempted.

Comment: Yes, that is the way

Comment: @FrankNielsen Thank you so much, not sure how I mark this as the answer and give you the credit?

Comment: I have posted an Answer, happy RabbitMQ'ing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using RabbitMQ it is possible to control how many messages that should be processed concurrent by calling:

`channel.BasicQos(0, <MaxConcurrentConsumerThreads>, false);`

So if chronology is important calling `channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);` ensures only 1 message is processed at a time.

Comment: I appreciate this was a while ago now, but now that the system is being tested properly I'm seeing data being processed out of sync which I was expected the QOS to prevent.  I applied the BasicQOS(0,1,false) to the queues, but also to an exchange that has two queues tied to it.  The data coming through the queue is not in order.  Does it also need to be applied to the queue attached to the exchange, if so how?

Comment: Unsure what you mean by `data being processed out of sync`? If you have 2 (or more) consumers/listeners to the same system - you will loose the chronology. So you can only have one consumer pr system, and can use the exchange if you need multiple systems to be in sync with the publisher.